# how to add googlemap layer when using leafletR

Tags: r, google-maps, leaflet

when I use `addBaseMap` function to add googlemap as my base map, it doesn't show anything on my browser. I have check the doc in leafletjs.com, it shows that `"{z} — zoom level"`,so i just simply replace the numeric zoom level into `"{z}"`.

what's more,it seems that leaflet is developed base on open source map, is there any problem when i use `styleCat` or `styleGrad` to set the style when the layer is googlemap?

R version : 3.2.2
leafletR version : 0.3-3

```
addBaseMap(
  name="google",
  title="Google Map",
  url="http://www.google.cn/maps/@24.5444691,118.0930683,{z}z"
)
map<-leaflet(base.map="google")
```

Answer (score 0):

The google maps api doesn't provide access to the map tiles directly through a url. While you can get googles map data in leaflet and openlayers by including the google maps js library and a plugin, this doesn't appear to be an option in `leafetR`. You could try one of the r packages designed to work with the google maps api such as `ggmap`, although this is for static maps. The style functions refer to vector data such as geojson, rather than the basemap which in most slippy maps is a pre-rendered .png or .jpg file. So you can apply styles to the data you overlay on the map, but if you want to custom style the basemap you should take a look at something like [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/).